# MS Graph - how to check for return code 204 after subscription is deleted?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

Just new to ms graph and also to .net.
I'm trying to write a method that deletes a notification subscription. The code itself seems to work.  But i need to know how to look up the actual return code from the upstream API instead of just sending back a 204.

Here's the code:

```
    [Route("msgraphnotification/{subscriptionId}")]
    [HttpDelete]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<Int> delete(string subscriptionId)
    {
        try{
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = await getAuthToken();
            await graphClient.Subscriptions["{subscription-id}"]
                .Request()
                .DeleteAsync();
            return 204; // this is what I want to fix.
            
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Console.Write(ex);
            return 404;
        }        
    }
```

Comment: What actual return code would you like to look up? I can see from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response) that if successful, this method returns a 204 No Content response code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to know the response code you can send HTTP request with the .Net Microsoft Graph client library.

```
// Get the request URL for deleting a subscription 
var requestUrl = client.Subscriptions["{subscription-id}"].Request().RequestUrl;

// Create the request message.
var hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, requestUrl);

// Authenticate HttpRequestMessage
await client.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);

// Send the request and get the response.
var response = await client.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);

// Get the status code.
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    throw new ServiceException(
        new Error
        {
            Code = response.StatusCode.ToString(),
            Message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        });
}
else
{
    var statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
}    
...
```